# Why is LocationLocal: Relative Alt dropping into negative values on a stationary drone?

Tags: dronekit-python

I'm running the Set_Attitude_Target example on an Intel Aero with Ardupilot. The code is working as intended but on top of a clear sensor error, that becomes more evident the longer I run the experiment.

In short, the altitude report from the example is reporting that in LocationLocal there is a relative altitude of -0.01, which gets smaller and smaller the longer the drone stays on.

If the drone takes off, say, 1 meter, then the relative altitude is less than that, so the difference is being taken out.

I ran the same example with the throttle set to a low value so the drone would stay stationary while "trying to take off" with insufficient thrust. For the 5 seconds that the drone was trying to take off, as well as after it gave up, disarmed and continued to run the code, the console read incremental losses to altitude, until I stopped it at -1 meter.

Where is this sensor error coming from and how do I remedy it?

Comment: For my case barometric sensor is only reliable when the altitude is >5m below that the value will be not accurate. Maybe you can use more reliable flight controller woth better barometric sensor or use Lidar/Sonar instead.

Comment: Yeah, my idea was to switch over to another sensor, but keep the code. It's a shame I can't use the built-in, but I'm glad you agree. Thank you.

Comment: Please mark this question as solved if you think you found the answer

Comment: To be honest, I don't. There must be a way to prevent the sensor from moving into negative values when the drone is standing still. I'll mark it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As per Agustinus Baskara's comment on the original post, it would appear the built-in sensor is simply that bad - it can't be improved upon with software.